# M.2 on Gigabyte LGA1151 Intel Z170 Mini-ITX DDR4

Tags: ssd, motherboard

Through a lack of knowledge I purchased a Samsung 850 EVO 250 GB M.2 SSD for the above board thinking I would see an increase in speed. The resultant speed is similar to any other SATA ssd and not faster.  Not wanting to make another expensive mistake I'm trying to match the correct M.2 ssd to my motherboard. The specs say the mobo supports M.2 Ver3 x4. Does the ssd I purchase have to say it supports x4 in order for me to get the full benefit of it's potential. Because the SS 850 EVO said only M.2 and nothing about lanes. Confusing.

Comment: If you specific the exact motherboard you have I submit an answer.

Comment: M.2 like SATA is backwards compatible. Your only constraint that is not is obviously the physical dimensions. Your motherboard is calling out specifically PCIe 3 x4. So it does not matter what the device supports the maximum speed you will get is what the motherboard supports.

Comment: Ah, great.  Thanks so much for coming back. I have the correct M.2 on order now.